# How to find checkbox with robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

i'm trying to get the locator of a checkbox named mycheckbox.

i tried:

```
//div[@class='ng-binding','mycheckbox']
```

It doesn't find the checkbox

The html code is:

```
<label ng-attr-for="{{ guidedNavigationFilter.id + '_ctrl_' + $index }}" 
    ng-bind="choiceLabel" class="ng-binding" 
    for="groupRadioClassification de privilège_ctrl_2">
    mycheckbox
</label>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the html is: <label ng-attr-for="{{ guidedNavigationFilter.id + '_ctrl_' + $index }}"
 ng-bind="choiceLabel" class="ng-binding" for="groupRadioClassification de privilège_ctrl_2">mycheckbox</label>

Comment: You can edit your question and add the correct HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for a `div` tag, but the element you want is a `label`. Maybe you need to reference the div containing the label element. It could look like this:

```
//div/label[@class='ng-binding']
```

or

```
//div/label[.='mycheckbox']
```

The element you see "looks" like a checkbox, but it is something that is dynamically controlled by AngularJS.

You did not posted the exact keyword and error message, so it is harder to guess the solution. I would say to try to `Focus` or `Click` the element, so it is activated as a Checkbox.

Comment: i tried //div/label[.='mycheckbox'] and the error message is : 20180915 17:42:56.068 : FAIL : InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@div/label[.="mycheckbox"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@div/label[.="mycheckbox"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: As you can see the error message is clear `The string '//*[@div/label[.="mycheckbox"]' is not a valid XPath expression.`. This is not what you reportedly sent. There is a `@div/label` inside brackets. In my answer I wrote div as an example, you are only person who can inspect your page for the correct XPATH expressions. Please use the browser tool to inspect the XPATH for your "checkbox".